# Insert to file from Hard Disk

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, streamwriter

I'm trying to make a small app (dictionary) that translates from English to Arabic and vice versa.
I have 2 files in the debug folder English.txt and Arabic.txt.

I am trying in my form to make it possible for the user to insert new words to the files but I don't know if `StreamWriters` are working while `StreamReaders` are.

I think that my `Seek` statements don't work the right way either.

Here is my code that I tried:

```
    FileStream englishFile = new FileStream("English.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    StreamReader engSR = new StreamReader(englishFile);
    StreamWriter engSW = new StreamWriter(englishFile);
    FileStream arabicFile = new FileStream("Arabic.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    StreamWriter arabSW = new StreamWriter(arabicFile);
    StreamReader arabSR = new StreamReader(arabicFile);


    string line = engSR.ReadLine();
    string[] arr = line.Split('|');
    int numberOfLines = int.Parse(arr[1]) + 1;


    englishFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    engSW.WriteLine("*|{0}", numberOfLines);
    arabSW.WriteLine("*|{0}", numberOfLines);


    englishFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    line = engSR.ReadLine();
    engSW.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", numberOfLines, englishin.Text);

    arabicFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    line = arabSR.ReadLine();
    arabSW.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", numberOfLines, arabicin.Text);


    arabicFile.Close();
    englishFile.Close();
```

Where `englishin` and `arabicin` are the two text-boxes.
Sadly there is no change that occurs in the file.

I have also tried :

```
string line = engSR.ReadLine();
        string[] arr = line.Split('|');
        int numberOfLines = int.Parse(arr[1]) + 1;


        englishFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        engSW.WriteLine("*|{0}", numberOfLines);
        arabSW.WriteLine("*|{0}", numberOfLines);


        //englishFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

        line = engSR.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
            line = engSR.ReadLine();
        engSW.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", numberOfLines, englishin.Text);

        //arabicFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

        line = arabSR.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
            line = arabSR.ReadLine();
        arabSW.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", numberOfLines, arabicin.Text);
```

I don't really know what's the problem with the writer.

Comment: Ummm... you haven't attached the files (that I can see)

Comment: When writing streams make sure you flush() before closing to make sure all data gets saved.

Comment: cannot upload it unfortunately

Comment: Why are you using flat files as opposed to some kind of embedded database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to close your `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, in onder to save your written text, you need to close `StreamWriter`

**Extra**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

System.IO is IDisposable, you should dispose it after read and write.

```
 private static void Main()
    {
        FileStream englishFile = new FileStream("English.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader engSR = new StreamReader(englishFile);
        StreamWriter engSW = new StreamWriter(englishFile);
        FileStream arabicFile = new FileStream("Arabic.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StreamWriter arabSW = new StreamWriter(arabicFile);
        StreamReader arabSR = new StreamReader(arabicFile);

        char delimiter = '|';
        try
        {
            englishFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            while(!engSR.EndOfStream){
                string line = engSR.ReadLine();
                string[] arr = line.Split(delimiter);

                for (int j = 0; j < arr.Count();j++ )
                {
                    if (j > 0)
                    {
                         arabSW.Write(delimiter);
                    }
                    String outStr = ConvertStr(arr[j]);
                    arabSW.Write(outStr);
                }

                arabSW.Write(arabSW.NewLine);
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            arabSW.Close();
            //arabSR.Close();
            engSR.Close();
            //engSW.Close();
            arabicFile.Close();
            englishFile.Close();
        }
    }
```

i tried this, it work well

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i have to make flush whenever i finished writing so after seeking to the begin and writing i should flush and at the end of the method i should close the StreamWriter as they said.

```
            string line = engSR.ReadLine();
            string[] arr = line.Split('|');
            int numberOfLines = int.Parse(arr[1]) + 1;


            englishFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            engSW.WriteLine("*|{0}", numberOfLines);
            arabicFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            arabSW.WriteLine("*|{0}", numberOfLines);
            engSW.Flush();
            arabSW.Flush();


            englishFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            line = engSR.ReadLine();
            engSW.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", numberOfLines, englishin.Text);

            arabicFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            line = arabSR.ReadLine();
            arabSW.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", numberOfLines, arabicin.Text);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            engSW.Close();
            arabSW.Close();
            arabSR.Close();
            engSR.Close();
            arabicFile.Close();
            englishFile.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You only have to flush once.  Not after every write to a file. I usually put the flush just before the close().  I flush is only required after every write if there is another thread that is reading from the stream.

Comment: @jdweng in this code I'm writing in each file 2 times and the beginning and at the end if i didn't flush after each time he will not remove the string from the buffer and send it to the file, so he will write both times at the end of the file ( the second one ) because i didn't give him order to move data from buffer to the file 
that what i have tried and it worked just like that

Comment: If you are writing to a file, "WHEN" you write doesn't make a difference as long as the data get written.  Provided nobody is attempting to read the file while it is being written.  So I really don't understand your issue.